wwwroot folder is not being received in the browser and localhost:{port} is a blank page. Blazor Server web app
I am working on a Blazor server web app. I created a new page and changed its route to @page "/" and changed the old / page to a new route.
When I load launch the program the default / route gets called, but nothing is rendered, and it doesn't receive anything in the network (see first screenshot).
But if I got to the route /counter which is an example page added, everything loads (second screenshot). Does anyone know what is causing this issue?


I have no idea what is wrong since I created a new test app and compared the program.cs and mine is the same + some additions that were working earlier.

Found out what happened. I am using MS Entra ID and I tried adding logout paths to the appsettings. Removing those logout paths fixed the problem because one of the paths lead to / route.
